# Eliminating delay in Simulink model

Tags: matlab, delay, simulink

I am developing a model in Simulink of a building, thermostat and air conditioner. My model is over predicting cooling and heating because of a 3 time-step signal delay.

Control is based on the input temperature. When the temperature in the room is above 27.2 C, the thermostat signal switches to "ON". This signal turns on the air conditioner, which should then remove heat from the room. In the layout diagram, the thermostat model and the performance map model are both "Masked" Sfunctions.

```
 1. Time  Temp [C]  CoolOnTemp CoolOffTemp CoolSignal Qsensible
 2. 8.43     27.11      26.2      27.2        0          0
 3. 8.45     27.201     26.2      27.2        0          0
 4. 8.47     27.29       26.2     27.2        1          0
 5. 8.48      27.38      26.2      27.2       1         -47121
 6. 8.50      26.59      26.2     27.2       1          -47160     
 7. 8.52      25.87      26.2     27.2       1          -46499
 8. 8.53      25.21      26.2     27.2       0           -45408
 9. 8.55      24.63      26.2     27.2       0           0
 10. 8.57     24.93      26.2     27.2       0           0
 11. 8.58     25.22      26.2     27.2       0           0
```

At time 8.45, the Core 1 temp is greater than 27.2 (its actual value is 27.201), however the Cooling Signal from the thermostat does not change to "1" until the next time step. A second delay occurs between the cooling signal and the air conditioner providing cooling (the Qsensible column). A third time step delay occurs between the cooling delivered by the air conditioner and the temperature responding in the room. Thus a total delay of 3 time-steps occurs between an "out of bounds" temperature condition and the desired response.

The same delay occurs when the air-conditioner should turn off, starting at time 8.52.

There are no purposeful delay blocks used between the thermostat and the air conditioner. While both blocks are Sfunctions, the Thermostat model has state variables (referencing previous time step values), but the air conditioner does not.

I appreciate any suggestions you can provide on how to eliminate 2 of these delays.

Comment: How do you calculate output from thermostat s-function? Is it all done in mdlOutputs? Does your model have multiple sample rates?

Comment: I have to initialize the cooling signals in the s-function because the on/off control setpoint changes based on if the air conditioner is currently running.

Comment: Once initialized, all calculations are in the function Outputs.

Comment: There are not multiple sample rates in this section of the model. A different section of my model has a different sample rate.

Comment: That rules out delay from s-function and rate transition. Which solver do you use? How did you log this data?

Comment: Maybe the system could be working fine, but the data acquisition is the one that is delayed. It is always worthy to check also this point.

Comment: I am using ode1 with a fixed time step as my solver.

Data is logged using "To Workspace" blocks attached to various signals throughout the model. The cooling signal and air conditioner cooling heat transfer are on the same "To Workspace" block.

Comment: @Navan So I just read the following on a mathworks tutorial: 

"If your model contains multiple S-Function blocks, the engine invokes a particular method for every S-function before proceeding to the next method. For example, the engine calls all the mdlInitializeSizes methods before calling any mdlInitializeSampleTimes methods. The engine uses the block sorted order to determine the order to execute the S-functions."

Does this mean that my thermostat and air conditioner output functions run simultaneously, instead of in series?

Comment: They do not run simultaneously. They run in series. But it could be in same time step. Are you able to run using simulink debugger and see when your s-function blocks are called.

Comment: Thanks @Navan I had not used the debugger before. It showed that the simulation order was completely backward. The air conditioner is simulated first, then the thermostat, then the room. So how do you change simulation order?

Comment: You can try changing "Block priority" property for each block in your model. http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/controlling-and-displaying-the-sorted-order.html#f13-91958.